# Heroku: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am on Chapter 8 of M. Hartle's Ruby on Rails tutorial. All the guard tests work fine and all the pages work perfectly when in local production. However after pushing to heroku (via bitbucket) I get the message:

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.<

instead of the home page.

I indeed checked the logs and found this, which I believe to be the root of the problem:

> 2015-07-20T21:30:30.461396+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] ! Unable to load application: LoadError: No such file to load -- test_helper
>   2015-07-20T21:30:30.462568+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': No such file to load -- test_helper (LoadError)<

what do I do now? Please help!

Comment: I think you are requiring a file called `test_helper` that either doesn't exist, or isn't being required correctly. Could you try and find that, and post it here?

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks a lot! It does indeed, inside the test directory. Here it is:

Comment: NV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
  include ApplicationHelper

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

Comment: # Logs in a test user.
  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
      post login_path, session: { email:       user.email,
                                  password:    password,
                                  remember_me: remember_me }
    else
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end

  private

    # Returns true inside an integration test.
    def integration_test?
      defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end
end

Comment: Cool, so the `test_helper.rb` file exists-- that's great. The other half of my comment was, I think somewhere else you are requiring that file, as in: `require 'test_helper'`. Have you tried searching for that, or just `require`?

Comment: Yes, the require 'test_helper' line is in a bunch of files strewn all over the place. That's how it is.. just require 'test_helper'.

Comment: If I recall the Hartl tutorial is test-driven. Is this also failing when the tests run? It definitely should be. If it is, you should get a much clearer error from that failure which should point to the problematic `require`.

Comment: You are doing something really wrong if you are requiring your `test_helper` on the production server.  You might want to use [grep](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/15-practical-unix-grep-command-examples/) to search for `test_helper` in your app and remove any occurrences outside of the tests folder.

Comment: That was the problem! There was an erroneous: 

require test_helper 

in the application_helper file in the app/helpers folder. I removed it and it now all works fine:). Can't thank you enough I'd been pulling my hair out all evening!